# internal hyperlink to a different sheet - Pandas+ OpenPyxl

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

I'm currently using pandas alongwith openpyxl engine.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = workbook
```

To create an external hyperlink, we use something like

```
my_data_frame.set_value(0, 'link', '=HYPERLINK("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000", 2000)')
```

How do I create a hyperlink internally that points to a different cell in a different sheet for the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from here - https://superuser.com/questions/163919/hyperlink-to-other-worksheet-using-hyperlink-function-in-excel

```
my_data_frame.set_value(0, 'link',  '=HYPERLINK("#Sheet1!A4","TEST")' )
```

Use the # symbol to signify this workbook, then the sheet name, then ! before the Cell / Range.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I click on the cell in the excel sheet. It says reference link isn't valid.
`dataframe4.set_value(0, 'link', '=HYPERLINK("#dataframe1!A4", test)')`

Comment: do you have a sheet named 'dataframe1' in your Excel File? Also, are you passing test as a string or not? In your initial example, you were passing cell contents of 2000, which wasn't a string. If you are passing 'test', put it in quotes

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo.

`my_data_frame.set_value(0, 'link', '=HYPERLINK("#mysheet1!A4", 2000)')`

Comment: Yes, it's working. However, there was a weird thing that happened. If I referenced a sheet with a name `My sheet` (two words with spaces) the link didn't work. However, when I referenced it to a sheet with a one word `test` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

With @emmet02's help, I have finally figured out this issue that I was facing.
Basically, the Hyperlink doesn't work (shows an invalid link alert on the excel sheet) if your reference sheet name has any special characters inside it, example a space, underscore, hyphen, etc.
Otherwise, below syntax works fine.
`=HYPERLINK("#'linked sheet name'!linked cell number","your message")`